I can't make certbot work with docker and nginx
I have a dockerized Django React Nginx webapp. This is my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13.2
    container_name: _database
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 
      POSTGRES_USER: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    container_name: backend_jkr
    volumes:
      # Source code directory:
      - type: bind
        source: ./backend
        target: /app/backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    # command: sh -c "cd /app/backend && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

  frontend:
      build:
        context: ./frontend/
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      container_name: frontend_jkr
      volumes:
        # Source code directory:
        - type: bind
          source: ./frontend
          target: /app/frontend
        - type: bind
          source: ./frontend/node_modules
          target: /app/frontend/node_modules
      ports:
        - "3001:3000"
        #3001 el primero en produccion
      environment:
        - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
        - NODE_ENV=development
        - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      depends_on:
        - backend
      stdin_open: true
      # command: npm start

  nginx:
      image: nginx:latest
      container_name: nginx_jkr
      build: .
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      volumes:
        - ./nginx.conf:/nginx.conf:ro
        - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
        - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot



      depends_on:
        - backend
        - frontend

  certbot:
   image: certbot/certbot
   volumes:
    - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
    - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot

And my nginx.conf file:
# Configuración para el backend Django
server {
    listen 8000;  # Puerto en el que se escucharán las solicitudes al backend
    server_name IP localhost example.net www.example.net ;  # Dirección IP del servidor

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;  # Nombre del servicio Docker del backend Django
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

# Configuración para servir el frontend React y manejar los desafíos de Certbot
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name IP example.net www.example.net;

    # Configuración para servir el frontend React
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    # Configuración para manejar los desafíos de Certbot
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
}

# Configuración SSL
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ip example.net www.example.net;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}

I am having this problem
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
Domain: example.net
Type:   unauthorized
Detail: IP: Invalid response from http://example.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/M9-0ibOqEMBk7v7140FwIlA2Qs-llCWxuSgJc9gl4No: "<!doctype html><html lang="en"><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="
Domain: www.example.net
Type:   unauthorized
Detail: 140.99.164.197: Invalid response from http://www.example.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/3oEOXqPs2qJHls81-ImXqKtoGFE8v5Hc8wWbmqbgjtk: "<!doctype html><html lang="en"><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="
Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains serve their content from the provided --webroot-path/-w and that files created there can be downloaded from the internet.
Some challenges have failed.

Have you changed the example.net for this post? In case no, you have to input your domain name in your nginx.conf next to server_name and in you certificate keys (that you have to generate before with your domain name. See https://certbot.eff.org/)
If you want a more simple tool you can use Nginx Proxy Manager, you can dockerize it, and manage directly into the web interface your SSL certificates
https://nginxproxymanager.com/

Yes I have changed the domain name for this post.
